# Hide a div using ng-hide based on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a div in which I use ng-init to initialize a variable:

```
<div class="block logo-container" ng-init="hideit=false">
</div>
```

Then there is another div which I want to hide or show based on that variable:

```
<div class="results-controllers"  ng-hide="hideit === true">
</div>
```

I want when a button is pressed the value of the variable to change and hide the div, so I wrote:

```
<button class="details-button-container" ng-click="hideit=true">
 </button>
```

But it doesnt work, I am not sure if this is the correct way, is that doaple? Should I use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is fine, you do not need to set anything in your controller. Everything you do in your markup will read and write on the `hideit` scope variable.

Change your ng-hide to

```
ng-hide="hideit==true" or ng-hide="hideit"
```

That should solve it. Also put some text on your button and your div to hide so you can see it works.

Working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/X8vkI36evUmA5ymlBy3a

Comment: I think the problem is that the ng-init is on the header, and I am not sure if it change, thank you for your example, it seems something else is the problem

Comment: No i think the problem is that you use === for comparison and in the inline attribute init, true might not be true, so using == for comparison is more foolproof (although using === is normally recommended). Consider flagging a post as accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.toggleDiv = function(){
        $scope.hideit =  $scope.hideit ? false : true;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/4gVFL/